# FreeBSD cannot use pathwatcher npm

Tags: npm, freebsd

I am getting crazy with the node npm [pathwatcher](https://github.com/atom/node-pathwatcher) on FreeBSD-10-2.

I tried this with node 0.10.40, 0.12.x, 4.2.x but none worked

Just simple

```
npm install pathwatcher
```

then small test script

```
var p = require('pathwatcher')
```

What ever release of `pathwatcher` I choose (6.2.5 (latest), 4.1.0, 5.0.1) I get the errors (depend on release and node)

```
1. node_modules/pathwatcher/build/Release/pathwatcher.node: Undefined symbol "_Z12PlatformInitv"  

2. module "pathwatcher" not found
```

The npm installation runs in any case without any error.

If I do the same on Debian/Ubuntu/MacOSX no problem.

What makes it special on BSD

Thanks or help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long answer short :-)

After having this discussion thread on freebsd forum at:

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/npm-pathwatcher-module-for-meteor-fails.53843/#post-302921

I created an update PR and that gots already merged

https://github.com/atom/node-pathwatcher/pull/95

So just use

```
npm install pathwatcher@6.3.0
```

Everythings works by now :-)